# Inheritance model in Conda environments

Tags: anaconda, conda, package-managers, miniconda

I want to have the following situation. Env A having few packages. Env B has all the packages inherited from A. B also has additional packages as per its requirement. Whenever I install a package in A - it should get automatically installed in B (but not vice versa). How to do it in conda ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda doesn't have any support for that. There was [some proposed feature discussion for this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1209) years back, but it is unclear where it went because the issue was migrated to the `conda-env` repo and is no longer accessible due to archiving(?).

You could try getting the issue/discussion reactivated. I think that's highly unlikely given [how notoriously slow conda dependency resolution already is](https://twitter.com/pathogenomenick/status/1093969420408500224). I'd guess the best route would be to write your own wrapper.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to proceed on writing the wrapper ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the discussion about this feature has resulted in the ability to ['nest' environments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#nested-activation), essentially activating environment A and then B on top of it. This delays the merging to activation time.

If you want to actually create separate environments, you can use a way to generate the `environment.yml` files for each. I use a master yaml file that I process with [jinja2-cli](https://pypi.org/project/jinja2-cli/). It contains conditionals that selectively include and exclude dependencies.